# Why doesn't ExpectConstructor() cause this test to fail?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, nunit, typemock

I'm a little confused as to the purpose of the `ExpectConstructor()` method on the `Mock` class in TypeMock 3.5.

I would have thought that calling `ExpectConstructor` would cause the `MockManager` to fail upon `Verify()` if the constructor is not called, i.e. if an instance of the mocked type is not instantiated.

However, calling `ExpectConstructor()` without specifying any arguments to that constructor doesn't appear to set that expectation - and so my test passes regardless.

My questions: Am I missing or misunderstanding something? If `ExpectConstructor()` isn't for verifying a constructor call, what's it for?

Consider these three NUnit tests which illustrate the problem:

```
[Test]
public void exampleTest1()
{
   MockManager.Init();
   Mock fooMock = MockManager.Mock(typeof(Foo));
   fooMock.ExpectConstructor().Args(10);

   Foo f = new Foo(10);   // Constructor called
   MockManager.Verify();  

   // This test passes, as expected...so far so good
}

[Test]
public void exampleTest2()
{
   MockManager.Init();
   Mock fooMock = MockManager.Mock(typeof(Foo));
   fooMock.ExpectConstructor();

   Foo f = new Foo();  // Constructor called
   MockManager.Verify();  

   // This test passes...also as expected
}

[Test]
public void exampleTest3()
{
   MockManager.Init();
   Mock fooMock = MockManager.Mock(typeof(Foo));
   fooMock.ExpectConstructor();

   // nb. not instantiating an instance of Foo

   MockManager.Verify();  

   // This test passes - why?!
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was reported as a bug [back in 2006](http://www.typemock.com/community/viewtopic.php?t=360). Supposedly it was going to be fixed (well, implemented - apparently it wasn't a bug, it was just an unimplemented feature...) but if it's still a problem now, I guess they didn't get round to it :(